# Give Android applciation (.apk) file root access

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I develope application in which i execute command which need to root access.

I also used java Process to execute command but it also not working.

For that i use c api using JNI ( NDK ) but it also not have access as root. because it having same permission as application.

My device as root access that's why it execute command in adb shell. but not 
from application.

is there any way to give root permission to application ?

Please give solution ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For give application system permission.

you need to sign application with the platform signature. You need to use keys located in `<root-of-android-source-tree>/build/target/product/security/` and add `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

**Steps :**

> sign application with the platform certificate
>   and run it with the system sharedUserId. These are the steps:
>
> - Build and flash to your Dream your own Android using http://source.android.com/documentation/building-for-dream. Use the
>     mkkey.sh script on
>     http://pdk.android.com/online-pdk/guide/release_keys.html to create
>     new certificates, including x509 certificates before you do 'make'.
> - In the `AndroidManifest.xml` of your application: under the `<manifest>` element, add the attribute `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"`.
> - Export an unsigned version of your Android application using Eclipse: right-click on the project >> Android Tools >> Export
>     Unsigned Application Package.
> - Use `<root-of-android-source-tree>/out/host/<your-host>/framework/signapk.jar` to sign your app using `platform.x509.pem` and `platform.pk8` in `<root-of-android-source-tree>/build/target/product/security`
>     generated earlier:
>
>   ```
>   java -jar signapk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8 YourApp-unsigned.apk YourApp-signed.apk.
>   ```
> - Install the app to your device:
>
>   ```
>   adb install YourApp-signed.apk
>   ```
> - Run your app
> - Use `adb shell ps` to confirm that your app is running as system.

Comment: While this may result in the code running as a more privileged user, it will not result in it running as root.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about the root access you must provide the permissions in your manifest file [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#FACTORY_TEST) and then after installing the application in your rooted phone the su app will ask for root access

Comment: it Not for use by third-party applications. "android.permission.FACTORY_TEST" it give error in adt